# GoogleWebRTC hangs (freezes) the main thread in swift native app (OpenVidu)

Tags: swift, multithreading, webrtc, webrtc-ios, openvidu

We have hanging problem (the app freezes due of main thread lock) with our iOS (swift) native app with *OpenVidu* implementation (which uses *GoogleWebRTC* under the hood). The specific conditions required: need to join existing room with at least 8 participants already streaming. With 6 participants it happens less often and almost never with less than 6. It doesn't hang if participants join one by one, only if you join the room with all other participants already streaming. This indicates concurrent nature of the issue.

The GoogleWebRTC hangs on `setRemoteDescription` call:

```
func setRemoteDescription(sdpAnswer: String) {
    let sessionDescription: RTCSessionDescription = RTCSessionDescription(type: RTCSdpType.answer, sdp: sdpAnswer)
    self.peerConnection!.setRemoteDescription(sessionDescription, completionHandler: {(error) in
        print("Local Peer Remote Description set: " + error.debugDescription)
    })
}
```

[image: main thread hangs]

As you can see on the screenshot above, the main thread hangs on `__psynch_cvwait`. No any other threads seems being locked. **The lock never releases** leaving the app completely frozen.

In the attempt to solve it I was trying the following:

1. I moved OpenVidu signaling server processing (RPC protocol) from the main thread into separate threads. This only caused the lock now occurs in the one of separate threads I created. It now doesn't block the UI, but blocks OV signaling. The problem persists.
2. I added the lock to process each signaling event (participant join event, publish video, etc) *synchronously* (one by one). This doesn't help either (it actually made the situation worse).
3. Instead of using GoogleWebRTC v. 1.1.31999 from Cocoapods, I downloaded the latest GoogleWebRTC sources, built them in release configuration and [included into my project](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/master/docs/native-code/ios/index.md). This didn't help to solve the issue.

Any suggestions/comments would be appreciated.
Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

The `signaling_thread` and `worker_thread` are both is waiting for something in the same kind of lock. Nothing of them execute any of my code at the moment of the lock.

I also tried to run in DEBUG build of `GoogleWebRTC`, in this case no locks happen, but everything works much slower (which is OK for debug, but we can't use this in Production).

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I tried to wrap in additional `DispatchQueue` for `offer` and `setLocalDescription` callbacks, but this changes nothing. The problem still well reproducible (almost 100% of time, if I have 8 participants with streams):

```
    self.peerConnection!.offer(for: constrains) { (sdp, error) in
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

            guard let sdp = sdp else {
                return
            }

            self.peerConnection!.setLocalDescription(sdp, completionHandler: { (error) in
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    completion(sdp)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the comment from OpenVidu team, the problem was solved by adding 100ms delay between adding participants who are already in the room. I would consider this more like a hack than a real solution, but I can confirm that it works both in test and in Production environment:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    for info in dict.values {
        let remoteParticipant = self.newRemoteParticipant(info: info)
        if let streamId = info.streamId {
            remoteParticipant.createOffer(completion: {(sdp) in
                self.receiveVideoFrom(sdp: sdp, remoteParticipant: remoteParticipant, streamId: streamId)
            })
        } else {
            print("No streamId")
        }
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The WebRTC Obj-C API can be called from any thread, but most method calls are passed to WebRTC's internal thread called `signalling thread`.

Also, callbacks/observers like `SetLocalDescriptionObserverInterface` or `RTCSetSessionDescriptionCompletionHandler` are called from WebRTC on the `signaling thread`.

Looking at the screenshots, it seems that the signaling thread is currently blocked and can no longer call WebRTC API calls.

So, to avoid deadlocks, it's a good idea to create your own thread / `dispatch_queue` and handle callbacks.

See
https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/0a52ede821ba12ee6fff6260d69cddcca5b86a4e/api/g3doc/index.md and
https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/0a52ede821ba12ee6fff6260d69cddcca5b86a4e/api/g3doc/threading_design.md
for details.

Comment: See my new EDIT in my question. Both signaling and working threads in `cv_wait`. None of them execute any of my code at the moment of lock. I also tried to dispatch queue for `peerConnection.setLocalDescription` callback as you suggested, but this changed nothing. I don't see any other callbacks which do anything significant or may lock on my side.

Comment: For `peerConnection` object, the only callbacks is used is: `setRemoteDescription` (but it does nothing besides `print`), `offer` (it immediately calls for `peerConnection.setLocalDescription`) and `setLocalDescription`, which do sending data to signaling server. The last one I tried to do into separate thread, but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: If so, I think you should file a bug at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/list . If you have minimal reproducible code that doesn't use a third-party library like OpenVidu, it will help you solve the problem.